# Screen regularly goes black during boot

Tags: boot, cpu, motherboard, gpu

Having a weird issue. When booting the PC I can always see Asus logo and can always get into BIOS, no problem. The issue happens *sometimes* when the OS (Fedora) starts loading. The screen goes black, starts cycling through modes, then goes to sleep.

What I've learned so far:

- The system boots correctly, probably. I know this because I get message in my headphones that it's *"connected to Fedora"*, which normally happens at the very end of boot sequence, about the same time as login screen appears.
- When the issue doesn't happen, everything works just as normal, no issues. CPU, GPU temperatures all fine, not even getting up to 70C during gaming.
- Sometimes I can boot into console mode by editing boot parameters and changing to mode 3, sometimes same problem with blank screen happens even when booting to console.
- When booting from Fedora USB all is fine while USB check is performed in console mode, after that blank screen. Although, not every time. Sometimes it's fine.
- When the system does boot successfully most of the time it works perfectly fine even under heavy load, but sometimes randomly freezes and goes into reboot (after which normally the issues come back again).
- One time during boot instead of normal Asus logo I got an old-school POST screen saying that "new CPU installed" and that I need to login to BIOS to set it up.

What I've tried so far:

- Changed HDMI cable
- Took system apart, checked all the cable connections. For the GPU changed power connectors around.
- Checked that CPU cooler didn't go loose. (Although very unlikely since temps are fine)
- Checked power connectors on the PU side. Also, PU is not hot, so probably not overheating either.
- I have X570 chipset so tried moving GPU to the second PCI-E 4.0x16 slot
- Removed and re-installed RAM. Switched modules around
- Tried resetting BIOS to defaults
- Tried rolling back to earlier kernel versions and also tried booting recovery version
- Re-installed OS (in the rare opportunity when successfully booted from USB)

So, to recap: the system appears to boot correctly but all is dark. Initially, I thought it might be power issue with increased power draw when booting and switching to graphical mode is tripping the PU, but I have an 850W Gold PU that's an overkill for the system and also this same thing happens when booting to console. All power and other connectors seem fine as well.

At the moment based on all that's happened it could be CPU, GPU or mobo, can't narrow it down at all. The weird POST screen seems to suggest something strange happened to the CPU. Next will try removing and inspecting it to see if there's any damage.

Any suggestions on how to narrow down the issue very welcome!

My system specs:

- CPU: Ryzen 5 5600x
- Motherboard: Asus PRIME X570-P ATX (BIOS updated for Ryzen 5)
- RAM: Kingston Fury Beast DDR4 32GB (2*16)
- GPU: Asus DUAL Radeon RX 6750XT
- PU: NZXT C850 C2 850W Gold

Comment: Try a different monitor.

Comment: @John, I'll try that but it's unlikely to be the issue. Right now my PC is not booting correctly but the monitor works perfectly fine with my work laptop.

Comment: So then if the issue is the PC, now time to get it serviced at a local shop.

Comment: @John I guess I'll have to. Was hoping to avoid the cost and diagnose the problem on my own. All bits and pieces are still on warranty so I can easily get it all fixed/replaced.

Comment: @John, actually it appears that you were right and I was wrong. I connected the PC to my TV and booted successfully 5 times with no issues. Reconnected to monitor and immediately got a black screen. At the same time, my work laptop connected to the same monitor works fine. The only difference is that the laptop runs at 4k * 30Hz and PC at 4k * 60Hz. Why would monitor suddenly have issues with 60Hz, but only *sometimes*?